# How can I combine Join these two tables?

Tags: mysql, join

How can I combine Join these two tables?

### Table 1

```
SELECT job_category.JobCategoryId, job_category.JobCategoryName, count(job_position.JobCategoryId) 
AS AvailableCategories
FROM job_position 
Right Outer JOIN job_category ON job_position.JobCategoryId = job_category.JobCategoryId
GROUP BY job_category.JobCategoryId, job_category.JobCategoryName
```

### Table 2

```
(SELECT job_category.JobCategoryId, job_category.JobCategoryName, count(job_position.ContactId) AS AllocatedJobs
FROM job_position 
Right Outer JOIN job_category ON job_position.JobCategoryId = job_category.JobCategoryId
WHERE job_position.ContactId > 0
GROUP BY job_category.JobCategoryId, job_category.JobCategoryName)
```

Thanks

Comment: What join do you want ? Inner / Outer  ?

Having a graphical representation of in a table format would make your question look neat.

Comment: Not clear to me what you want to see as a result - some sample data & expected output please?

Comment: Those are 2 queries, not 2 tables and nearly identical queries at that; did you paste the wrong content?

Comment: Sorry, Id like job_category.JobCategoryId, job_category.JobCategoryName, count(job_position.ContactId), count(job_position.JobCategoryId) as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be like this

```
Select T1.JobCategoryId, T1.JobCategoryName, T1.AvailableCategories, T2.AllocatedJobs    
FROM    
 (SELECT job_category.JobCategoryId as JobCategoryId, job_category.JobCategoryName as JobCategoryName, count(job_position.JobCategoryId) 
AS AvailableCategories
FROM job_position 
Right Outer JOIN job_category ON job_position.JobCategoryId = job_category.JobCategoryId
GROUP BY job_category.JobCategoryId, job_category.JobCategoryName) as T1 

INNER JOIN 

((SELECT job_category.JobCategoryId as  T2JobCategoryId, job_category.JobCategoryName as T2JobCategoryName, count(job_position.ContactId) AS AllocatedJobs
FROM job_position 
Right Outer JOIN job_category ON job_position.JobCategoryId = job_category.JobCategoryId
WHERE job_position.ContactId > 0
GROUP BY job_category.JobCategoryId, job_category.JobCategoryName)) as T2
ON T1.JobCategoryId = T2.T2JobCategoryId
```